# How to POST data to php template in angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http

New to angular, new to php, new to programming at all.
I'm using ui-router, and here's how it looks like:

```
.state('admin', {
        url:'/admin',
        templateUrl: 'admin/admin.php',
        controller: 'AdminController'
    })
    .state('admin.auto', {
        url: '/auto',
        templateUrl: 'admin/states/auto.php',
        controller: 'AdminAutoController'
    })
    .state('admin.auto.update', {
        url: '/update',
        templateUrl: 'admin/states/autoupdate.php',
        controller: 'AdminAutoUpdateController'
    })
```

Routing works fine, on my admin.auto view, I've got list of autos with "edit" and "delete" buttons. I get the list from MySQL database.

```
<div ng-repeat="auto in autos">
    <p>{{auto.mark}}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateAuto(auto.mark)">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```

So now I need to post auto.id to auto update nested view, so i can select proper table row. At this point I'm struggling to post any data to update view, just to find out if it works, so here it is:

```
.controller('AdminAutoController', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
$http.get('php/DBZ.php').success(function(data) {
    $scope.autos = data;
});

$http({
    url: "admin/states/autoupdate.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param({id:"some id"})
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
});

}])
```

And, finally, my PHP:

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['id'];
echo $test;
?>
```

So, as a result, i get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id on line 4
```

Sorry for my English, and thanks for any help!

Comment: in your view change ng-click="updateAuto(auto.mark)" to ng-click="updateAuto(auto)" and in your controller wrap your $http call into a function like so: updateAuto = function(auto) so you can use auto.id as id param. then on success assign the response value to auto, so it updates your view.